# How to pass variable to mailgun default email template

Tags: php, mailgun

I use mailgun and integrated with php. The mail sends fine without error. I create a default template in mailgun(Action Template). In that template there is a button. My Issue is

How to i pass a parameter to that button a tag
MY code is

```
$mg = Mailgun::create('MY API');
// Now, compose and send your message.
$result = $mg->messages()->send('MY DOMAIN NAME', [
'from' => 'support@figjam.net',
'to' => $email,
'subject' => 'Confirm Your E-mail',
'html' => ' <p>Please confirm your email address by click the link below <br>
<a href="'.$base_url.'/activate.php?id='.base64_encode($lastID).'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">CLICK TO ACTIVATE YOUR ACCOUNT</button></a></p>'
'template'    => 'verifyemail'      
]);
```

I need to pass variable to that template **verifyemail**

Kindly Help me fix this.
Thanks

Comment: do you mean `$lastID` to be passed?

Comment: The docs have [a pretty clear example](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#templates), did you read them?

Comment: @Akam Yes the $lastID is my variable. The verifyemail is a template that is created in mailgun site. In that template there is a button called Confirm Email. For that button i need to pass my variables.

Comment: It looks like links to Mailgun's docs don't work, so my link above just goes to the intro, not to the templates section as it should.  [Click the "Templates" link](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#templates) in the navigation on the left - there is an example of how to use templates and variables right there in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have `myvariable` with value `someVariableValue`

```
  'template'    => 'verifyemail',
  'v:myvariable' => 'someVariableValue',
]);
```